# Create subset table from Pandas dataframe with hierarchical index in a loop

Tags: python, loops, pandas, subset, multi-index

I want to iterate through a hierarchical index panda dataframe and print a subsets based on "group1" level.

here is my dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group1': ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d','d','d','d','d'],
                        'group2': ['c','c','d','d','d','e','f','f','e','d','d','d','e'],
                        'value1': [1.1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4],
                        'value2': [7.1,8,9,10,11,12,43,12,34,5,6,2,3]})

df = df.set_index(['group1', 'group2'])
```

This is what it looks like:

```
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
a      c          1.1     7.1
a      c          2.0     8.0
a      d          3.0     9.0
b      d          4.0    10.0
b      d          5.0    11.0
b      e          6.0    12.0
c      f          7.0    43.0
d      f          8.0    12.0
d      e          9.0    34.0
d      d          1.0     5.0
d      d          2.0     6.0
d      d          3.0     2.0
d      e          4.0     3.0
```

I can successfully print a SINGLE subset based on group1 like this:

```
print df.xs('a', level=0)  

        value1  value2
group2                
c          1.1     7.1
c          2.0     8.0
d          3.0     9.0
```

But how can I put this in a loop to print a subset for each group of elements in 'group1'?

My failed attempt:

```
for group1, group2 in df.index: 
    print df.xs(group1, level=0)
```

This printed a subset for each index instead of grouping them together (hope that makes sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_level_values` on the index to return just those index values at that level, additionally call `unique` as what is returned are duplicate index values for each sublevel row.

```
In [35]:

for gp in df.index.get_level_values(0).unique():
    print (df.xs(gp, level=0))
        value1  value2
group2                
c          1.1     7.1
c          2.0     8.0
d          3.0     9.0

[3 rows x 2 columns]
        value1  value2
group2                
d            4      10
d            5      11
e            6      12

[3 rows x 2 columns]
        value1  value2
group2                
f            7      43
f            8      12

[2 rows x 2 columns]
        value1  value2
group2                
e            9      34
d            1       5
d            2       6
d            3       2
e            4       3

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what `groupby` is for (iteration gives your the groupname,group):

```
In [13]: for g, grp in df.groupby(level='group1'):
    print grp
   ....:     
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
a      c          1.1     7.1
       c          2.0     8.0
       d          3.0     9.0
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
b      d            4      10
       d            5      11
       e            6      12
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
c      f            7      43
       f            8      12
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
d      e            9      34
       d            1       5
       d            2       6
       d            3       2
       e            4       3
```

Most of the time you actually want to do something with it though, e.g.

```
df.groupby(level='group1').sum()
```